# Possibilities of dividing a class in groups with several criteria

Tags: math, combinations, np

I have to divide a class of 50 students writing a dissertation in 10 different discussion groups of 5 members each. In theory, there are 1.35363x10^37 possible ways of doing this, which is just the result of {50!}/{(5!^10)*10!)}, if it is already decided that the groups will consist of 5.

However, each group is to be led by a facilitator. This reduces the number of possible combinations considerably, because each facilitaror has one field of expertise among 5 possible ones, which should be matched to the topics the students are writing about as much as possible. If there are three facilitators with competence A, three with competence B, two with competence C, one with competence D and one with competence E, and 15 students are assigned to A, 15 to B, 10 to C, 5 to D and 5 to E, the number of possible combinations comes down to 252 505.

But both students and facilitators keep advocating for the use of more criteria, instead of just focusing on field of expertise. For example, wanting to be in a group of students that know each other, or being in a group with a facilitator that has particular knowledge of a specific research method.

I am trying to illustrate my intuitive reasoning, which tells me that each new criteria increases the complexity/impossibility of the task, if the objective is a completely efficient solution. But I can't get my head around expressing this analytically in a satisfactory manner.

Is my reasoning correct, that adding criteria would reduce the amount of possibilities that can be discarded following the inclusion-exclusion principle, thus making the task more complex, adding possible combinations? I also think that if the criteria are not compatible (for example if students that know each other are writing about different topics, and there aren't enough competent facilitators), certain constraints become inviable.

Comment: I think you are mistaken about there being just 2,118,760 ways to partition 50 people into 10 groups of 5. You used a binomial coefficient, but it would make more sense to use a multinomial coefficient. There are more like 4.91 x 10^43 such partitions (or 1.35x10^37 if you just care who is grouped with who and not who is in the first group, who is in the second group, etc.) Beyond that, your question is too vague to answer. Once you know what the criteria are you can ask about ways to satisfy them, but right now you just seem to be thinking out loud.

Comment: Thanks! You are right. The binomial coefficient gives the number of possible combinations of one single group of students. This number is larger, when considering the possible combinations of the remaining 9 groups. I'm updating the post to include this. My question is vague because we have not decided upon other specific criteria. These could be methods and/or students knowing each other from beforehand. My purpose is not necessarily to find the one or an efficient solution, but to show/illustrate the complexity involved, so that all can agree to limit the number of criteria and accept this.

Comment: Sounds like you have more of a political problem than a mathematical/computer programming problem. Obviously complications are, well, complications. Do you really need confirmation of that? In any event, I added an answer which might or might not help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish between computational complexity and human complexity. Adding constraints almost automatically increases the human complexity of the problem in the sense that it means that there is more to wrap your mind around. But -- it isn't true that the computational complexity increases. At least sometimes it decreases.

For example, say you have a set of 200 items and you want to determine if there is a subset of them which satisfy some constraint. Depending on the constraint, There might be no feasible way to do it. After all, 2^200 is *much* too large to brute-force. Now add the constraint that the subset needs to have exactly 3 elements. Now all of a sudden it *is* possible to brute force (just run through all 1,313,400 3-element subsets until you either find a solution or determine that none exist). This is enough to show that it isn't true that adding a constraint always makes a problem intrinsically more difficult. In the discrete case a new constraint can cut down on the size of the search space in a way that can be exploited. In the continuous cases it can reduce degrees of freedom and thus lower the dimension of the problem. This isn't to say that it always makes it easier. Probably as a rule of thumb, additional constraints *tend* to make a problem more difficult.

Your actual problem isn't spelled out enough to give concrete advice. One possibility (and one way to handle a proliferation of somewhat extraneous constraints) is to divide the constraints into hard constraints which need to be satisfied and soft constraints which are merely desired but not strictly needed. Turn it into an optimization problem: find the solution which maximizes the number of soft-constraints that are satisfied, subject to the condition that it satisfies the hard constraints. Perhaps you can formulate it as an [integer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) problem and hopefully find an exact solution. Or, if it is easy to generate solutions that satisfy the hard constraints and it is easy to mutate one such solution to obtain another (e.g. swap two students who are in different groups), then an [evolutionary algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_algorithm) would be a reasonable heuristic.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications and good suggestions! I am trying to formulate it as a transportation problem with constraints, where N is the number of students = 50 and G is one of the 10 possible groups (from A to J). I have defined "p" as the preference weight each student assigns to each group. "x" becomes a binary variable, where x_NG=1 is student N assigned to a group G. My problem is then to maximize the sumproduct x*(p), when the sum of x in each group is equal to 5 and the sum of x for each student is equal to 1. However, Excel's solver keeps violating the constraints...

Comment: I identified the problem. Excel's solver ony manages 200 decision variables. When I reduced the decision matrix to 200, and adapted the restrictions, the solver managed to find an exact solution that maximizes the sum product of preference and the binary decision variables. I guess I will have to use another interface that handles more variable entries. There are many options. I appreciate suggestions, if you have any experience with this.

Comment: @AVT_DB Why stick to Excel? There are various open-source solvers.

Comment: I tried some things in Python and Matlab, but I appreciate the intuitive and illustrative way of solving such a problem in a spreadsheet. Especially since I want to explain this to others who might not be familiar with Matlab or Python. Excel's solver is too limited, but Open Office Calc has actually a pretty good solver. I also added a constraint, which is a minimum for the preference weight for each student, in order to guarantee a certain degree of student satisfaction with the solution. The problem is linear and the system finds an exact solution.